# Correlation matrix

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, correlation

I have this example of a correlation matrix in my notes:

$$R = E[XX^T]$$
$$n = 3, E[X_i X_{j}^*] = 2^{|i-j|}$$
$$R = \left[
\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0.5 & 0.25 \\
        0.5 & 1 & 0.5 \\
        0.25 & 0.5 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

It seems as if the off-diagonal entries are $\frac{1}{2^{|i-j|}}$ instead of the given $2^{|i-j|}$.

Comment: Yes, the minus is missing from the exponent in the formula for covariance. In fact, squared covariance cannot be larger than the product of variances, which makes this example impossible with a plus.

Comment: @zhoraster, thank you!